# Problem with Sentinel-2 NDVI export to TIFF in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2

I'm trying to calculate and export NDVI rasters extracted from Sentinel-2 using the script:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/a9247db3f03e9514eb0378d1f59e9447

Source code: [Export images in google earth engine with date name](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279964/export-images-in-google-earth-engine-with-date-name)

When I run it for coordinates

```
  [27.493905, 53.73073],
  [27.493905, 53.990091],
  [27.849634, 53.990091],
  [27.849634, 53.73073]
```

it works properly and I get correct NDVI values (-1 - 1).

But when I run this script on  coordinates

```
  [47.11727, 54.71504],
  [47.11727, 54.942041],
  [47.411848, 54.942041],
  [47.411848, 54.71504]
```

it still works and show the first calculated NDVI in GEE but after I export rasters on local computer from Google Drive I get strange values of NDVI and can't visualise NDVI in GIS...

Low : -3,40282e+38
High : 3,40282e+38

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using ArcMAP to visualize exorted rasters? Did you compute histogram?

Comment: Yes, I try to visualize rasters in ArcMap and I computed histograms. But it didn't help.

Comment: Change raster representation to a shorter range (-1 to 1) and use info tool to check pixels

Comment: I tried but it looks like the raster is invalid and without spatial reference. So I think it's something wrong with my script. Anyway thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was incorrect projection of output image (EPSG). After I fixed it all rasters export properly.

Comment: Can you please add the edited answer here?