# Copying the system:time_start property from a filtered Image Collection to a Mosaic/Image in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm creating a script to do a time-series analysis over a large date range, preview/(`Map.addLayer`) the results on one specific day, and have that Map result be exportable.

The timeseries section is working well, and I have mosaics filtering for specific days to be mapped and then exported, but I would like to be able to add the date in some form on the `description:` of the `Export.image.toDrive` section. That appears to be extremely difficult as once you `.mosaic` an `ee.ImageCollection`, it removes all `properties` except for `system:index`, which is wiped of the original data and makes it useless.

I've seen [this great example](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/279964/export-images-in-google-earth-engine-with-date-name), however I don't need or want it to be iterated over multiple images in an `ImageCollection` over a large date range, just the filtered Mosaic on one particular day.

I've tried a few methods (`.copyProperties`, `.get`) found from other Stack Exchange/Overflow questions to no avail, but the closest I've gotten is through `.set` and `.getInfo()` in [This Example Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/6d7a2fc4f4f34cec6dabb111981b23dd):

```js
// ### IMPORTED GEOMETRY ###
var Geom = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* shown: false */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-8.511494599189746, 52.915278842998354],
          [-8.511494599189746, 52.895607287195],
          [-8.478964768257129, 52.895607287195],
          [-8.478964768257129, 52.915278842998354]]], null, false);

// ### FILTER PARAMETERS ### 
//These apply the parameters to both L1C and L2A imagery and stop repetitive data entry
// CLOUD % format '00' , numbers only without quotes
var MIN_CLOUD_PERCENT = 20;
// START DATE & END DATE format: 'YYYY-MM-DD', include the quotes
var START_DATE = '2022-01-01';
var END_DATE = '2022-04-01';
// PREVIEW DATES are used to align all the visible map layers to the same date
var FRST_PRVW_DATE = '2022-03-30';
var LAST_PRVW_DATE = '2022-04-01';
// BOUNDS can either be a drawn geometry shape within GEE, or an imported SHP file
// See: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/table_upload#upload-a-shapefile
var BOUNDS = Geom;
// ZOOM is based on GEE's 1-24 level system. Larger number = Larger Zoom
var ZOOM = 14;
// PARAMETERS END - You don't need to change anything below this line to make the script function

// ### MISC ###
//Prints out the Parameters set
print('Filtering available Sentinel 2 imagery between ' + START_DATE + ' & ' + END_DATE + ' with ' + MIN_CLOUD_PERCENT + '% cloud over the area of interest.');
// Centre based on the Geometry (Region of Interest, Zoom Level)
Map.centerObject(BOUNDS, ZOOM, print('Map centered on Region of Interest'));
// Sets the default Map to Terrain mode (Roadmap overlain with hillsahde) 
Map.setOptions("TERRAIN");

// ### LAYER VISUALISATION ###

// Truecolour (R-G-B) Visualisation
var rgbVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.35,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

// ### CLOUD MASKING ###
// Sentinel 2 Cloud Masking Function using the 60m Cloud Mask Band
/*  Function to mask clouds using the Sentinel-2 QA band
 *  @param {ee.Image} image Sentinel-2 image
 *  @return {ee.Image} cloud masked Sentinel-2 image
 */
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
   return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}
print('Sentinel 2 Cloud Mask Function Complete');

// ### IMAGE COLLECTIONS ### 
//Load and Map L1C imagery with the filter parameters applied
                  /*
                  *  Load Sentinel-2 'Harmonized' Top Of Atomsphere (L1C) data
                  *  Dataset details: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_HARMONIZED
                  *  HARMONIZED makes sure scenes after 25 January 2022 have the same DN ranges as older L1C scenes.
                  *  Harmonised L1C Data is available from Sentinel 2 Launch (2015-06-23) onwards.
                  */
var S2_L1C = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED')
                  // Filter by Date Period (YYYY-MM-DD)
                  .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
                  /* 
                  *  Pre-filter to get less cloudy granules
                  *  'Default' is aiming for 10% cloud
                  *  Dependent on availability of cloud-free imagery in the time period set
                  *  Longer periods will take longer to load
                  */
                  .filter(ee.Filter.lte('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', MIN_CLOUD_PERCENT))
                  // Select only image tiles that fall within the Geometry (Region of Interest) to reduce processing time
                  .filterBounds(BOUNDS)
                  // Applies the S2 Cloud Masking Function to each image in the IC
                  .map(maskS2clouds)
                  // Clips each image in the IC by the Bounds to reduce processing time further
                  .map(function(image) {
                    return image.clip(BOUNDS);
                  });

print('Time, Date, Bounding, and Cloud Tile Filtering parameters set for Imagery');

// ### MAPPING AND MOSAICING ###
// Add the pre-clipped IC to the map
Map.addLayer(S2_L1C.filterDate(FRST_PRVW_DATE, LAST_PRVW_DATE),rgbVis,'L1C_Filtered_IC');

var FilteredMosaic = S2_L1C.filterDate(FRST_PRVW_DATE, LAST_PRVW_DATE).mosaic().set("system:time_start", S2_L1C.filterDate(FRST_PRVW_DATE, LAST_PRVW_DATE).getInfo());
Map.addLayer(FilteredMosaic, rgbVis, 'L1C_Mosaic');


// ### EXPORTING ###
// Can't export the entire IC because it's an IC, it has to be an Image (hence the Mosaic)
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: FilteredMosaic.visualize(rgbVis), // Sets the image to keep the current Visualisation parameters
    region: Geom,
    description: 'L1C_Demo_' + FilteredMosaic.date().format('yy-MM-dd').getInfo(), // Sets the name of the image(s)
    folder: 'GEETestDemo', // The destination folder for the imagery in your Account's Google Drive
    scale: 'nominal', // Returns requested image AT TRUE SCALE
    crs: 'EPSG:3857', // CRS - This is the standard GEE Web Mercator projection, WGS84.
    maxPixels: 1e13, // Max Pixel amount - always required as the default limit is very small
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});
```

I still get a horrendously long error, but *it does give my Mosaic a `system:time_start` property, and within there is the original data inside*, albeit all of it when I only want one Property:

```
Line 109: Image.date: Image has a 'system:time_start' property which is not a number: 
{features=[{bands=[{crs_transform=[60, 0, 499980, 0, -60, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[547, 617], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B1, dimensions=[38, 38]}, {crs_transform=[10, 0, 499980, 0, -10, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[3286, 3706], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B2, dimensions=[222, 222]}, {crs_transform=[10, 0, 499980, 0, -10, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[3286, 3706], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B3, dimensions=[222, 222]}, {crs_transform=[10, 0, 499980, 0, -10, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[3286, 3706], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B4, dimensions=[222, 222]}, {crs_transform=[20, 0, 499980, 0, -20, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[1643, 1853], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B5, dimensions=[111, 111]}, {crs_transform=[20, 0, 499980, 0, -20, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[1643, 1853], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B6, dimensions=[111, 111]}, {crs_transform=[20, 0, 499980, 0, -20, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[1643, 1853], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B7, dimensions=[111, 111]}, {crs_transform=[10, 0, 499980, 0, -10, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[3286, 3706], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B8, dimensions=[222, 222]}, {crs_transform=[20, 0, 499980, 0, -20, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[1643, 1853], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B8A, dimensions=[111, 111]}, {crs_transform=[60, 0, 499980, 0, -60, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[547, 617], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B9, dimensions=[38, 38]}, {crs_transform=[60, 0, 499980, 0, -60, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[547, 617], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B10, dimensions=[38, 38]}, {crs_transform=[20, 0, 499980, 0, -20, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[1643, 1853], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B11, dimensions=[111, 111]}, {crs_transform=[20, 0, 499980, 0, -20, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[1643, 1853], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=B12, dimensions=[111, 111]}, {crs_transform=[10, 0, 499980, 0, -10, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[3286, 3706], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=QA10, dimensions=[222, 222]}, {crs_transform=[20, 0, 499980, 0, -20, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[1643, 1853], data_type={min=0, max=429496.75, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=QA20, dimensions=[111, 111]}, {crs_transform=[60, 0, 499980, 0, -60, 5900040], crs=EPSG:32629, origin=[547, 617], data_type={min=0, max=6.553500175476074, precision=float, type=PixelType}, id=QA60, dimensions=[38, 38]}], type=Image, properties={system:time_start=1648727202698, system:footprint={coordinates=[[[-8.511494599189746, 52.895607287195], [-8.495229683723437, 52.895607287195], [-8.478964768257129, 52.895607287195], [-8.478964768257127, 52.915278842998354], [-8.495229683723439, 52.915278842998354], [-8.511494599189747, 52.915278842998354], [-8.511494599189746, 52.895607287195]]], type=Polygon}, system:index=20220331T114349_20220331T114345_T29UNU}}], id=COPERNICUS/S2_HARMONIZED, bands=[], type=ImageCollection, version=1652454890835642, properties={date_range=[1435017600000, 1647993600000], period=0, system:visualization_0_min=0.0, type_name=ImageCollection, keywords=[copernicus, esa, eu, msi, radiance, sentinel], system:visualization_0_bands=B4,B3,B2, thumb=https://mw1.google.com/ges/dd/images/sentinel2_thumb.png, description=<p>Sentinel-2 is a wide-swath, high-resolution, multi-spectral
imaging mission supporting Copernicus Land Monitoring studies,
including the monitoring of vegetation, soil and water cover,
as well as observation of inland waterways and coastal areas.</p><p>The Sentinel-2 data contain 13 UINT16 spectral bands representing
TOA reflectance scaled by 10000. See the <a href="https://sentinel.esa.int/documents/247904/685211/Sentinel-2_User_Handbook">Sentinel-2 User Handbook</a>
for details. In addition, three QA bands are present where one
(QA60) is a bitmask band with cloud mask information. For more
details, <a href="https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/technical-guides/sentinel-2-msi/level-1c/cloud-masks">see the full explanation of how cloud masks are computed.</a></p><p>Each Sentinel-2 product (zip archive) may contain multiple
granules. Each granule becomes a separate Earth Engine asset.
EE asset ids for Sentinel-2 assets have the following format:
COPERNICUS/S2/20151128T002653_20151128T102149_T56MNN. Here the
first numeric part represents the sensing date and time, the
second numeric part represents the product generation date and
time, and the final 6-character string is a unique granule identifier
indicating its UTM grid reference (see <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_Grid_Reference_System">MGRS</a>).</p><p>The Level-2 data produced by ESA can be found in the collection
<a href="COPERNICUS_S2_SR">COPERNICUS/S2_SR</a>.</p><p>Clouds can be mostly removed by using
<a href="COPERNICUS_S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY">COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY</a>.
See
<a href="https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorials/community/sentinel-2-s2cloudless">this tutorial</a>
explaining how to apply the cloud mask.</p><p>For more details on Sentinel-2 radiometric resolution, <a href="https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric">see this page</a>.</p><p><b>Provider: <a href="https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/product-types/level-1c">European Union/ESA/Copernicus</a></b><br><p><b>Revisit Interval</b><br>
  5 days
</p><p><b>Bands</b><table class="eecat"><tr><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Description</th></tr><tr><td>B1</td><td><p>Aerosols</p></td></tr><tr><td>B2</td><td><p>Blue</p></td></tr><tr><td>B3</td><td><p>Green</p></td></tr><tr><td>B4</td><td><p>Red</p></td></tr><tr><td>B5</td><td><p>Red Edge 1</p></td></tr><tr><td>B6</td><td><p>Red Edge 2</p></td></tr><tr><td>B7</td><td><p>Red Edge 3</p></td></tr><tr><td>B8</td><td><p>NIR</p></td></tr><tr><td>B8A</td><td><p>Red Edge 4</p></td></tr><tr><td>B9</td><td><p>Water vapor</p></td></tr><tr><td>B10</td><td><p>Cirrus</p></td></tr><tr><td>B11</td><td><p>SWIR 1</p></td></tr><tr><td>B12</td><td><p>SWIR 2</p></td></tr><tr><td>QA10</td><td><p>Always empty</p></td></tr><tr><td>QA20</td><td><p>Always empty</p></td></tr><tr><td>QA60</td><td><p>Cloud mask</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan=100>
      Bitmask for QA60
<ul><li>
          Bit 10: Opaque clouds
<ul><li>0: No opaque clouds</li><li>1: Opaque clouds present</li></ul></li><li>
          Bit 11: Cirrus clouds
<ul><li>0: No cirrus clouds</li><li>1: Cirrus clouds present</li></ul></li></ul></td></tr></table><p><b>Image Properties</b><table class="eecat"><tr><th scope="col">Name</th><th scope="col">Type</th><th scope="col">Description</th></tr><tr><td>CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Granule-specific cloudy pixel percentage taken from the original metadata</p></td></tr><tr><td>CLOUD_COVERAGE_ASSESSMENT</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Cloudy pixel percentage for the whole archive that
contains this granule. Taken from the original metadata</p></td></tr><tr><td>DATASTRIP_ID</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Unique identifier of the datastrip Product Data Item (PDI)</p></td></tr><tr><td>DATATAKE_IDENTIFIER</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Uniquely identifies a given Datatake. The ID contains
the Sentinel-2 satellite, start date and time, absolute orbit
number, and processing baseline.</p></td></tr><tr><td>DATATAKE_TYPE</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>MSI operation mode</p></td></tr><tr><td>DEGRADED_MSI_DATA_PERCENTAGE</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Percentage of degraded MSI and ancillary data</p></td></tr><tr><td>FORMAT_CORRECTNESS</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Synthesis of the On-Line Quality Control (OLQC) checks
performed at granule (Product_Syntax) and datastrip (Product
Syntax and DS_Consistency) levels</p></td></tr><tr><td>GENERAL_QUALITY</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Synthesis of the OLQC checks performed at the datastrip level (Relative_Orbit_Number)</p></td></tr><tr><td>GENERATION_TIME</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Product generation time</p></td></tr><tr><td>GEOMETRIC_QUALITY</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Synthesis of the OLQC checks performed at the datastrip level (Attitude_Quality_Indicator)</p></td></tr><tr><td>GRANULE_ID</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Unique identifier of the granule PDI (PDI_ID)</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B1</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B1 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B2</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B2 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B3</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B3 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B4</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B4 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B5</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B5 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B6</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B6 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B7</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B7 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B8</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B8 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B8A</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B8a and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B9</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B9 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B10</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B10 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B11</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B11 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_AZIMUTH_ANGLE_B12</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence azimuth angle average for band B12 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B1</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B1 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B2</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B2 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B3</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B3 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B4</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B4 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B5</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B5 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B6</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B6 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B7</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B7 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B8</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B8 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B8A</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B8a and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B9</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B9 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B10</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B10 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B11</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B11 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_INCIDENCE_ZENITH_ANGLE_B12</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing viewing incidence zenith angle average for band B12 and for all detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_SOLAR_AZIMUTH_ANGLE</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing sun azimuth angle average for all bands and detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MEAN_SOLAR_ZENITH_ANGLE</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean value containing sun zenith angle average for all bands and detectors</p></td></tr><tr><td>MGRS_TILE</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>US-Military Grid Reference System (MGRS) tile</p></td></tr><tr><td>PROCESSING_BASELINE</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Configuration baseline used at the time of the product
generation in terms of processor software version and major Ground
Image Processing Parameters (GIPP) version</p></td></tr><tr><td>PRODUCT_ID</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>The full id of the original Sentinel-2 product</p></td></tr><tr><td>RADIOMETRIC_QUALITY</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Based on the OLQC reports contained in the Datastrips/QI_DATA with RADIOMETRIC_QUALITY checklist name</p></td></tr><tr><td>REFLECTANCE_CONVERSION_CORRECTION</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Earth-Sun distance correction factor</p></td></tr><tr><td>SENSING_ORBIT_DIRECTION</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Imaging orbit direction</p></td></tr><tr><td>SENSING_ORBIT_NUMBER</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Imaging orbit number</p></td></tr><tr><td>SENSOR_QUALITY</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Synthesis of the OLQC checks performed at granule
(Missing_Lines, Corrupted_ISP, and Sensing_Time) and datastrip
(Degraded_SAD and Datation_Model) levels</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B1</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B1</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B2</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B2</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B3</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B3</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B4</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B4</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B5</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B5</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B6</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B6</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B7</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B7</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B8</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B8</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B8A</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B8a</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B9</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B9</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B10</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B10</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B11</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B11</p></td></tr><tr><td>SOLAR_IRRADIANCE_B12</td><td>DOUBLE</td><td><p>Mean solar exoatmospheric irradiance for band B12</p></td></tr><tr><td>SPACECRAFT_NAME</td><td>STRING</td><td><p>Sentinel-2 spacecraft name: Sentinel-2A, Sentinel-2B</p></td></tr></table><p><b>Terms of Use</b><br><p>The use of Sentinel data is governed by the <a href="https://scihub.copernicus.eu/twiki/pub/SciHubWebPortal/TermsConditions/Sentinel_Data_Terms_and_Conditions.pdf">Copernicus
Sentinel Data Terms and Conditions.</a></p><style>
  table.eecat {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 13px;
  }
  table.eecat td, tr, th {
  text-align: left; vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px solid gray; padding: 3px;
  }
  td.nobreak { white-space: nowrap; }
</style>, source_tags=[eu, esa, copernicus, sentinel], visualization_0_max=3000.0, provider_url=https://earth.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/product-types/level-1c, title=Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-1C, sample=https://mw1.google.com/ges/dd/images/sentinel2_sample.png, tags=[copernicus, esa, eu, msi, radiance, sentinel], system:visualization_0_max=3000.0, product_tags=[msi, radiance], provider=European Union/ESA/Copernicus, visualization_0_min=0.0, system:visualization_0_name=RGB, visualization_0_name=RGB, visualization_0_bands=B4,B3,B2}}
```

So my question: Is there a way to slice this down to the intended `system:time_start` data, or even just the original `system:index`? I was looking into possibly using the callback property of `getInfo()`, but I'm still a novice so I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. I just want the date information from the filtered Image Collection on the Mosaic, and most importantly on the exported images so that they can be distinguished between multiple dates.

I could always fallback to just using the `FRST_PRVW_DATE` variable I already have as a simpler prefix/description, but that will always make the date incorrect (-1 day before the actual). Perhaps an alternative way would be to just have "`FRST_PRVW_DATE + 1 Day`" in the Export description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring out my own question, so I'll just leave the solution here:
[Example Solution](https://code.earthengine.google.com/f8cb33abc7cb5149133d0c07153df8c5)

```js
// ### IMPORTED GEOMETRY ###
var Geom = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-11.11113449176787, 54.43227206644482],
          [-11.11113449176787, 51.305678054127945],
          [-8.093069992866504, 51.305678054127945],
          [-8.093069992866504, 54.43227206644482]]], null, false);
          
// Filtering imagery for hypothetical timeseries
var START_DATE = '2022-01-01';
var END_DATE = '2022-05-01';
// Filtering imagery to display a particular day on the Map.
var FRST_PRVW_DATE = '2022-03-30';
var LAST_PRVW_DATE = '2022-04-01';
// Setting the Area of Interest
var BOUNDS = Geom;

// Centers the Map on the Area of Interest
Map.centerObject(BOUNDS, 8);

// Sentinel 2 Image Collection and Cloud Masking
function maskS2clouds(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA60');
  // Bits 10 and 11 are clouds and cirrus, respectively.
  var cloudBitMask = 1 << 10;
  var cirrusBitMask = 1 << 11;
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
   // Applies the cloud masking conditions to the IC, and adds the date of acquisition into each image for easy timeseries organising later
   return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000).copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
}
var S2_L2A = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR_HARMONIZED')
            .filterDate(START_DATE, END_DATE)
            .filterBounds(BOUNDS)
            .map(maskS2clouds);
print('S2_L2A_Image Collection', S2_L2A); // Produces 1066 Images/Elements 

// Visualisation settings
var rgbVis = {
  min: 0,
  max: 0.35,
  bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'],
};

// Add the Hypothetical timeseries range of imagery to Map (turned off by default because it's intensive)
Map.addLayer(S2_L2A, rgbVis, 'S2_L2A_IC', false);

// Filtering the timeseries range to just a particular day (i.e. 2022-03-31)
var S2_L2A_Filt = S2_L2A.filterDate(FRST_PRVW_DATE, LAST_PRVW_DATE);
print('S2_L2A_IC Filtered (2022-03-31)', S2_L2A_Filt); // Produces 13 Images/Elements that fit the date
// Selecting the first Element of the Filtered IC
var S2_L2A_Filt_1st = S2_L2A_Filt.first();
print ('S2_L2A_Filtered First Element', S2_L2A_Filt_1st); // Produces 1 Image (Element 0 of the previous var)

// Properties Extraction
// Pulls out the System:Index Property of every element in the Filtered IC, puts it in a dictionary, and inserts it into the Properties 
var SystemIndex = S2_L2A_Filt.map(function (image) {
  return image.set('SysIndex', image.toDictionary(['system:index']));
});
print('Property keys and values of S2_L2A_Filt', SystemIndex); // Returns the same 8 Images/Elements, but now with a 'SysIndex' Object in each Element
// This is done because just trying to extract the original system index brings up null values, or a "this is not a function" error.

// Aggregates the Dictionary into an Array
var list = SystemIndex.aggregate_array('SysIndex');
print('Agg. Array List', list); // Produces the List with only the values of the Dictionary from each Element
// Gets only the first Element of the List
var list_1st = list.get(0);
print('S2_L2A_IC, The First System:Index', list_1st); // Prints the first (0) Elements' System:Index Property. 

//Mosaic the S2_L2A_IC that was filtered to the day (Line 39), and gives it the property of the first Element of the List (Line 56)
var S2_L2A_Mosaic = S2_L2A.filterDate(FRST_PRVW_DATE, LAST_PRVW_DATE).mosaic().set(list_1st);
print('S2_Mosaic w/ Properties of the S2_L2A_Filtered_1st', S2_L2A_Mosaic); // The Mosaic now was the same System:Index of the First Element in the IC's List
// Add the Mosaic of one day's imagery to Map
Map.addLayer(S2_L2A_Mosaic, rgbVis, 'S2_L2A_Mosaic_2022_03_31');

// Gets the System:Index of the Mosaic as a String
var index = S2_L2A_Mosaic.get('system:index');
print('System Index in String',index); // "20220331T114349_20220331T114345_T28UGB"
/* Sentinel 2 Imagery follows this naming convention:
*  START TIME:'(YYYYMMDD)T(HHMMSS)_' + END TIME:'(YYYYMMDD)T(HHMMSS)_' + UTM MGRS ID: 'T00ABC'
*  So slicing it to the first 13 characters gives you the swath start time, to the minute
*  This is extracted using getInfo() which can then be put into the image name.
*/
var index = index.getInfo().slice(0,13);
print('Sliced System:Index', index); // "20220331T1143" (i.e. 11:43 AM on March 31st, 2022)

// Just to demonstrate the System:Index being added to the Exported name.
// 'Run' to see the other properties are correct before confirmation of download
// ### DON'T RUN THE TASK ON THE INITIATE EXPORT MENU ### It will be very large.
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: S2_L2A_Mosaic.visualize(rgbVis), // .visualize keeps the visualisation parameters for the image for export
    description: 'S2_L2A_'+ index, // The Tasks will show a "S2_L2A_20220331T1143" Download available
    folder: 'EE_OutputTest', // The destination folder for the imagery in your Account's Google Drive
    scale: 'nominal', // Returns requested image AT TRUE SCALE (i.e. 10m).
    crs: 'EPSG:3857', // The standard GEE and Wider Internet's Web Mercator Projection, WGS84.
    region: Geom, // The Area of Interest
    maxPixels: 1e13,
  });
```

In short;

- Run a `.map` function to pull the `system:index` out of each image in the Image Collection, put them into a Dictionary, and add that to the Properties of each Image in the Image Collection. (This is important, as trying to extract the original `system:index` or `system:start_time` results in null). This has the added bonus of being able to extract different and/or multiple properties, should anyone wish.
- Run `.aggregate_array` the created dictionary into a List. I can't explain why you need to do this, only that if you don't and try the next step on the Dictionary function itself, it will bring up an 'Invalid Type' error.
- Create a variable to `.get(0)` the created List to show only the `system:index` property of the first Element/Image from the List.
- In the `.Mosaic`, also `.set` the List_1st variable to the Mosaic. This puts the `system:index` property of the first Image/Element agg.array List into the Mosaic.
- Then just create a variable to `.get('system:index')` on the Mosaic, and another to `getInfo()` and `slice()` to the string of interest (*YYYYMMDD***T***HHMM*). You could include another slice() section to this to include the Tile number (the last characters), or format it.
- In the `description` section of the Export, insert the index variable and you'll have a simple method to insert the date from the first of an Image Collection to your Mosaic, and have it on the Export name.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you shouldn't use **getInfo** method in this way.

```
.
.
.
var FilteredMosaic = S2_L1C.filterDate(FRST_PRVW_DATE, LAST_PRVW_DATE).mosaic().set("system:time_start", S2_L1C.filterDate(FRST_PRVW_DATE, LAST_PRVW_DATE).getInfo());
.
.
.

    description: 'L1C_Demo_' + FilteredMosaic.date().format('yy-MM-dd').getInfo(), // Sets the name of the image(s)
.
.
.
```

The "system:time_start" property is a date object and your description task only a string object. So, by using an arbitrary date of ee.Date('2000') and 'L1C_Demo_' as name task prefix, your script runs properly by using **getInfo** as in following code snippet.

```
var date = ee.Date('2000');
var date_string = date.format().slice(0,10);

print(date_string);

var FilteredMosaic = S2_L1C.filterDate(FRST_PRVW_DATE, LAST_PRVW_DATE).mosaic()
.set("system:time_start", date);
Map.addLayer(FilteredMosaic, rgbVis, 'L1C_Mosaic');

print(FilteredMosaic);

// ### EXPORTING ###
// Can't export the entire IC because it's an IC, it has to be an Image (hence the Mosaic)
Export.image.toDrive({
    image: FilteredMosaic.visualize(rgbVis), // Sets the image to keep the current Visualisation parameters
    region: Geom,
    description: ee.String('L1C_Demo_').cat(date_string).getInfo(), // Sets the name of the image(s)
    folder: 'GEETestDemo', // The destination folder for the imagery in your Account's Google Drive
    scale: 'nominal', // Returns requested image AT TRUE SCALE
    crs: 'EPSG:3857', // CRS - This is the standard GEE Web Mercator projection, WGS84.
    maxPixels: 1e13, // Max Pixel amount - always required as the default limit is very small
    fileFormat: 'GeoTIFF'
});
```

After running complete code in this [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/cbe1787f2038e327a372fb1fd611ed9c), I got result of following image. Task ran successfully and its name has date appended as expected.

[image]

Comment: Ah, so I can't use `````getInfo()```` as I'd envisioned, thank you for the explanation. 

My criticism lies with that the ````date_string```` is manually defined and applies it to the Mosaic and the description. I would like to know if the original ````system:```` objects could be pulled automatically from the IC and applied to the Mosaic and description.

I appreciate the method you outlined, but is there no method to get the ````system:time_start```` or ````system:index```` object/properties of the ImageCollections as a string for the Description of the Mosaic?

Comment: If I have to manually enter the ````date_string```` variable myself, what would be the advantage of this to reading off the ````system:time_start```` Object from the Image Collection via the Inspector and add the date to the title when I confirm the export in the Tasks tab?